# How to solve Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3

Tags: java, exception

I am a newbie and i have no idea what is wrong with my code here. I am going to write both the questions and my code here. Please if anyone can help me.
So the question says:
You have to tell the total number of chores the person can perform in the given time.
The first input is the total number of time the user got.
The second input is the total number of chores the user wants to perform.
The final inputs is the time it will take to complete each task.

and here goes my code:

public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

```
    int totalmins, chores=0, eachtime, totalchores, counter=0;


    // getting the input
    System.out.println("Enter the total time:");
    totalmins=scan.nextInt();
    while (totalmins>100000) {
        System.out.println("Enter again. Less than 100000:");
        totalmins=scan.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Enter the total chores:");
    chores=scan.nextInt();

    int [] time = new int[chores];

    for (int i=1; i<chores; i++) {
        System.out.println("Enter time:");
        eachtime=scan.nextInt();
        time[i]=eachtime;
    }
   // arranging in ascending order
    for (int i=0;i<time.length; i++) {
        if (time[i] > time[i+1]) {
            int temp = time[i];
            time[i]=time[i+1];
            time[i+1]=temp;
        }

        }
        for (int i=0;i<time.length; i++) {
            totalchores=time[i] + time[i+1];
            counter++;

            if (totalchores>totalmins) {
                counter=counter-1;
                System.out.println(counter);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you had to guess, what would you say the error is (given `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`).

Comment: I think my for loop counter for the array is giving the problem?

Comment: Try to -1 in your for loop. Or go eat a bagel.

Comment: Step through the for loop. What is the last value of `i`? What is the value of `i+1` with relation to the size of your array?

Comment: I have tried time.length-1 but my program wont even go past the first for loop infact it shows the error on the second input whithin the loop

Comment: This is why every programming student should be taught to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I think the point that you're missing is that in an array of length 3, the entries are numbered 0, 1 and 2.  If you try to use entry number 3, you'll get that exception.  But that's exactly what you're doing - all of your loops continue until `i = 2` (including that case), but then you go ahead and try to use entry `i + 1` of the array.